# How to do this query? Many different categories of products, need a limit on number of products per category

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a query which selects products from a table:

```
Select * FROM products WHERE category_id in (1,2,3,4,5) LIMIT 100
```

I would like to impose a limit on the number of entries returned for each category rather than the sum of all categories.

The way I have it sometimes it could return 100 products for just one category then just stop before it gets to any of the others

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id = 1 LIMIT 100
UNION 
SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id = 2 LIMIT 100
UNION
SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id = 3 LIMIT 100
UNION 
SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id = 4 LIMIT 100
UNION 
SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id = 5 LIMIT 100
```

This will return the first 100 records for each category from 1 through 5.